# Big Query SQL - group over all possible levels of aggregation

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, quantile

Let's say I've a table with columns `value, dim1, ..., dim 10` and I want to get the median for all possible grouping over the columns `dim1`, ..., `dim10`. ie over all subgroups, all subgroups across any 9 dimensions, any 8...

I can do

```
SELECT * FROM
( 
    SELECT 
        APPROX_QUANTILES(value, 100)[SAFE_ORDINAL(50)] as median,
        dim1, ..., dim10
    FROM table
    GROUP BY dim1, ..., dim10
)
UNION ALL
( 
    SELECT 
        APPROX_QUANTILES(value, 100)[SAFE_ORDINAL(50)] as median,
        dim1, ..., dim9
        NULL as dim10
    FROM table
    GROUP BY dim1, ..., dim9
)
UNION ALL
... --2^10 subtables
```

but that's quite long, especially if `table` is computed on the fly. Is there a better way?

I'm working with big query but the answer might not be specific to big query

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Until BigQuery supports GROUP BY CUBE, I found this was the most compact/readable way to get the desired aggregation over every combination of groups:

```
SELECT 
    APPROX_QUANTILES(value, 100)[SAFE_ORDINAL(50)] as median,
    dim1, ..., dim10
FROM table,
UNNEST ([dim1, 'ALL']) AS dim1,
...
UNNEST ([dim10, 'ALL']) AS dim10
GROUP BY dim1, ..., dim10
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want [`GROUP BY ROLLUP`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax):

```
SELECT APPROX_QUANTILES(value, 100)[SAFE_ORDINAL(50)] as median,
       dim1, ..., dim10
FROM table
GROUP BY ROLLUP(dim1, ..., dim10);
```

This is available in both Standard and Legacy SQL (and that probably explains why the more common `GROUPING SETS` syntax is not used).

Comment: I feel OP wanted CUBE which is not supported [yet] in BigQuery

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant . . . You're right.  I saw the logic in the query, but the OP does specifically want 2^10 rows.  Strange question.

Comment: There is a [relevant feature request for CUBE](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905688), so consider "starring" it to express your support. While not the only signal, we do use them to help prioritize the features to work on.

Comment: Yes CUBE looks like what I need. I actually want the 2^10 rows. I'm aggregating metrics for later display that can be broken down in any way. It will still be much much less than the number of rows in the original table and with my different group values won't add up to more than 1M.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my temporary solution that seems to do what CUBE would do:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION makeGroups(group_names ARRAY<STRING>)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var res = [];
  var n = 1 << group_names.length;
  for(var i=0; i<n; i++) {
    res.push(group_names.map(function(g, idx) { return (i >> idx) % 2 == 1 ? (g || 'null') : 'any' }).join(':::'));
  }
  return res;
""";

WITH data AS
(
  SELECT
    value,
    makeGroups([dim1, ..., dim10]) AS group_names
  FROM
    table
)

SELECT 
  SUM(1) as counts,
  APPROX_QUANTILES(value, 100)[SAFE_ORDINAL(50)] as median
  group_name
FROM
(
  SELECT
    value,
    group_name
  FROM data
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(data.group_names) as group_name
)
GROUP BY
  group_name
```

I could map the group name that looks like `dim1_value::...::dim10_value` back to columns but I kind of like the distinction between `NULL` from the original value (here `'null'`) and from the aggregation (here `'any'`)